# With the verb "bastare", does the construction "Bastava ce l'avesse fatta ..." act like a past conditional?

Tags: tenses, conditional-mood

> Avremmo dovuto provare per saperlo! **Bastava** ce l'**avesse fatta** uno solo di noi.

Given the use of the past conditional "avremmo dovuto" in the preceding sentence, I assume that they are talking about a past (conditional) event that actually didn't take place:

> They wanted to try doing something but ***couldn't*** – they ***should have*** –  and it ***would have been*** enough if just one of them ***had done*** it / ***succeeded***.

When the verb "bastare" is involved, do you usually use the combination of *Indicativo Imperfetto* "bastava" and *Congiuntivo Imperfetto* "avesse fatta" like this to convey a past conditional meaning?

---

Incidentally, could it be that "ce" in "Bastava ce" is a colloquial or regional variant of "che" used to introduce a subordinate clause?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think I can translate the answer today (working day) , maybe other users will do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78425/discussion-on-question-by-alone-zee-with-the-verb-bastare-does-the-constructi).

Comment: @Alone-zee Please, if you must continue this discussion do so in the chatroom above. I'm thinking of writing a meta post about this this evening. I'll link to it when I do.

Comment: @Alone-zee Here's the [meta question](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/when-are-dictionaries-the-answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very common colloquial form of the verb ***[bastare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bastare/)*** used in the following meanings:

> ***Often used in impersonal form***, “*basta, è sufficiente, non occorre altro, e simili”*: *per oggi credo che basti; bastava che m’avvertisse*.
>
> ***Special locutions*** : a) *”Basta che, purché”*: basta che tu lo chieda, te lo dànno subito; even with the infinitive (and without *che*): basta chiedere con buone maniere, si ottiene tutto ciò che si vuole.

A more correct version is

> Avremmo dovuto provare ...sarebbe bastato che...

The usage of the particle “ce” is correct, since it does not substitute the conjunction “che” (here omitted) but is part of the following verbal phrase (ce l’avesse fatta, see: [farcela](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/farcela)) .

(Treccani/DeMauro)

Comment: Hi. What is the exact function of "ce" or "ci" in "farcela"? And I hadn't expected that the Congiuntivo "avesse fatta" could immediately follow "bastava" like this without having "che" in between. So is this construction colloquial?

Comment: @Alone-zee Yes, this construction is colloquial. Regarding *farcela*, if the link in the answer does not help you, why don't you ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @DenisNardin Interesting. Do you mean that the Imperfetto construction "Bastava ce l'avesse fatta" itself with the conditional meaning is colloquial, or the fact that the conjunction "che" is dropped is colloquial?

Comment: @Alone-zee Both are colloquial, but dropping the *che* more so (and in fact I'd go as far as discouraging the latter).